# duration of execution of a program linked to the presence of C++ builder on the computer

Tags: c++, executable, builder

I use Builder C++ XE7

some procedures of my program are instant when I run them under borland, but are much longer if I move the program to another computer.

Many thanks for your help

Comment: Thank you for the information. But what is the question and where is your source code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: It's not a problem of code for a specific program, it is a general problem that I encounter on several programs